# Check if a value already exist in db and bound dgv before adding/saving

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a bound datagridview and I want to check before inserting a username if that username already exists or not in my database. I insert values to dgv and database through a textBox. Thanks in advance..

```
    private void user1BindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Validate();
        this.user1BindingSource2.EndEdit();
        this.tableAdapterManager2.UpdateAll(this.databasDataSet);

    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'databasDataSet.user1' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.user1TableAdapter2.Fill(this.databasDataSet.user1);

        user1DataGridView.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        passwordTextBox.PasswordChar ='*';

    }

    private void add_new_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            this.user1BindingSource2.AddNew();

    }

    private void save_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        this.Validate();
        this.user1BindingSource2.EndEdit();
        this.tableAdapterManager2.UpdateAll(this.databasDataSet);
    }




    private void delete_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.user1BindingSource2.RemoveCurrent();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To validate anything on the server-side (the existence of the username in your case) there is `CustomValidator` control. Add it to your page and attach it to your username `TextBox`. Then place your validation code to `ServerValidate` event handler.